# How to gradually restart a service in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

We have some services that once every month we need to restart the services because we need to reload some resources in them and the best way to do that is to restart the services, I wonder if there are any options in docker swarm to restart a service (with many replicas) gradually, like restart a replica and then restart the next one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the update by customizing the `update_config`-section.
Example:

```yaml
deploy:
  replicas: 2
  update_config:
    parallelism: 1
    delay: 30s
    order: start-first
```

In that case, we have 2 replicas. Only one will be updated simultaneously, which happens by starting a third replica. If the 3rd one is stable, the old replica will be shut down. After 30s, the same process will start for the second "old" replica.

[Detailed documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#update_config)